# Background tasks are being queued and not executed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

I've implemented the BackgroundQueue as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks), and as shown:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    backgroundQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async ct =>
    {
        //Do some work...
    });

    return Ok();
}
```

I registered the BackgroundQueue with Autofac as:

```
builder.RegisterType<BackgroundQueue>()
    .As<IBackgroundQueue>()
    .SingleInstance();
```

So far so good. I call my controller action and the task is added to the queue. And there it stays without being executed.

So how do I get the task to execute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BackgroundQueue` implementation that you took from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks) is only one part to the solution: The background queue will just keep track of the jobs that you want to be executed.

What you will also need is right below that in the docs: The `QueuedHostedService`. This is a background service that gets registered with the DI container and is started when the application starts. From then on, it will monitor your `BackgroundQueue` and work off jobs as they get queued.

A simplified example implementation of this background service, without logging or error handling, could look like this:

```
public class QueuedHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IBackgroundQueue _backgroundQueue;

    public QueuedHostedService(IBackgroundQueue backgroundQueue)
    {
        _backgroundQueue = backgroundQueue;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var workItem = await _backgroundQueue.DequeueAsync(stoppingToken);
            await workItem(stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```